# Split elements, remove and then join them back

Tags: r

I have the following `data.frame`:-

```
a <- data.frame(col_1 = c("1001", "1002", "1003", "1004", "1005"),
                col_2 = c("1002|3932|1003", "1033|1004|1005", "1022|1220|1005", "1001|1002",
                          "2122|1002|1004"))
```

What I want to do is from each element in `col_2`, remove all those those elements which do not exist in `col_1`. So that the resulting `data.frame` is as following

```
b <- data.frame(col_1 = c("1001", "1002", "1003", "1004", "1005"),
                col_2 = c("1002|1003", "1004|1005", "1005", "1001|1002", "1002|1004")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Base R option :

Split the string on `|`, keep only the values which are present in `col1` and paste the string back.

```
a$col_2 <- sapply(strsplit(a$col_2, '|', fixed = TRUE), function(x) 
                  paste0(intersect(x, a$col_1), collapse = '|'))
a

#  col_1     col_2
#1  1001 1002|1003
#2  1002 1004|1005
#3  1003      1005
#4  1004 1001|1002
#5  1005 1002|1004
```

---

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

a %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(col_2, sep = '\\|') %>%
  filter(col_2 %in% unique(col_1)) %>%
  group_by(col_1) %>%
  summarise(col_2 = paste0(col_2, collapse = '|'))
```

Answer (score 0):

additional option

```r
library(tidyverse)
a <- data.frame(col_1 = c("1001", "1002", "1003", "1004", "1005"),
                col_2 = c("1002|3932|1003", "1033|1004|1005", "1022|1220|1005", "1001|1002",
                          "2122|1002|1004"))

b <- data.frame(col_1 = c("1001", "1002", "1003", "1004", "1005"),
                col_2 = c("1002|1003", "1004|1005", "1005", "1001|1002", "1002|1004"))

a %>% 
  mutate(
    tmp = map(
      .x = strsplit(col_2, split = "\\|"), 
      .f = ~str_subset(.x, str_c(a$col_1, collapse = "|")))
  ) %>% 
  mutate(col_2 = map_chr(tmp, ~str_c(.x, collapse = "|"))) %>% 
  select(-tmp)
#>   col_1     col_2
#> 1  1001 1002|1003
#> 2  1002 1004|1005
#> 3  1003      1005
#> 4  1004 1001|1002
#> 5  1005 1002|1004
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this with `str_extract_all`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
a %>%
   mutate(col_2 = map_chr(str_extract_all(col_2, str_c(col_1, collapse="|")), 
         str_c, collapse="|"))
```